# Elasticsearch phrase mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following phrase:

> It's never happened to me – Messi Player of Barcelona to Cristiano Ronaldo star of Real
>   Madrid thanks Juve fans for ovation.

And a simple elasticsearch document called `Player`:

```
"firstName": {
   "localizedValues": {
      "de": "",
      "en": "Cristiano"
   }
},
"lastName": {
   "localizedValues": {
      "de": "",
      "en": "Ronaldo"
   }
}
"teamAssociations": [
   {
      "active": true,         
      "teamName": {
         "localizedValues": {
            "de": "",
            "en": "Real Madrid"
         }
      }
]
```

What I'm trying to do, is a simple mapping approach,
Try to find a Player that plays for a team, in this case I would like to get Cristiano Ronaldo and Messi, and if a team in that phrase is found, then have that to boost the score for more relevance.

What I have tried so far:

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match" : {
                "query":    " It's never happened to me – Messi to Cristiano Ronaldo star of Real Madrid thanks Juve fans for ovation ", 
                "fields": [ "firstName.localizedValues.*", "lastName.localizedValues.*", "teamAssociations.teamName.*^3" ],
                "type":       "cross_fields",
                "analyzer":   "english"
             }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But that gets also other players that plays for Read Madrid, which I don't want.
Also in that title I might not have the team name, just players, so the team should be optional but important if found.

How can I approach this problem ?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to add the optional fields in a should clause. Try something like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": " It's never happened to me – Messi to Cristiano Ronaldo star of Real Madrid thanks Juve fans for ovation ",
          "fields": [
            "firstName.localizedValues.*",
            "lastName.localizedValues.*"
          ],
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      },
      "should": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": " It's never happened to me – Messi to Cristiano Ronaldo star of Real Madrid thanks Juve fans for ovation ",
          "fields": [
            "teamAssociations.teamName.*"
          ],
          "type": "cross_fields",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you want a specific factor check this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_boosting_query_clauses.html